# Mount NTFS-format external USB drive

Tags: mount, ntfs

i'm trying to search a student device with CAINE. I'm trying to pull an image of the drive for analysis, first I'm trying to mount an external USB hard drive `sdb` with read and write privileges so I can write to it and copy the image with Guymager tool. If i just try to mount with CAINE it automatically write protects anything.

I've tried first as root user: `mkdir /media/forensicA`
Then: `mount -o rw /dev/sdb /media/forensicA`

but I get this error:

> "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb/, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Trying to mount a NTFS Win 10 partition, booting of a live USB of CAINE.

Comment: If the USB hard drive has a partition table you might have to mount `/dev/sdb1` (for the first partition) instead of `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: Make sure that you _never_ mount the target device with write access.  To be frank: if this is serious digital forensics, having the evidence handled by someone who does not even know how to mount a disc is not really _help_ at all, and is actually a liability.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdbX /media/forensicA` and replace X with your partition number (1 for the first partition, 2 for the second,...)

Comment: I'd use `ntfs3g` instead and also be sure ntfs3g is installed. `ntfs` only won't let OP write

Comment: Yes, `ntfs-3g` should be installed. On my Debian `-t ntfs` and `-t ntfs-3g` is the same (fuseblk mounted in rw).